# How to change the dropdown list value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have this dropdown list,

a,b,c,

and 2 radio buttons rdbButton1 and rdbButton2.WHen i click on  rdbButton1 dropdownlist will appear and when i click on rdbButton2 i have to set dropdownlist value as a.how can i change dropdownlist value (i want to change it in javascript or jquery)

Comment: You'll do well to post the code you already have.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id_of_the_option_element').val('new_value');
$('#id_of_the_option_element').html('new_caption');
$('#id_of_the_option_element').attr('selected','selected');
```

search how autoid works by searching "autoID asp.net" on google. This may help, too.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx

you should go to the source view to check how the ID's of the html elements change.

Comment: i tried this,when i debug code it will show new value,but dropdownlist is not setting to new value.

Comment: @user1414253 i added the third line for that

Comment: i tied this ,2nd line of code is changing my dropdownlist means i have a,b,c.i want to set to a.it is making all as a,a,a.

Comment: @user1414253 each option should have a different client id, you can choose static client id's for each option

Comment: i gave 1,2,3 to a,b,c,but now also changing all values to a. and in 2nd line of ur code ('new_caption').what i have to give?please do help i m fesher to this js and jquery,don know much